# How do I define usings in MVC 3 Razor View Engine across entire site?

Tags: .net, web-config, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wrote a simple extension method for UrlHelper:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    private const string ImagesFolder = "~/Images";

    public static string Images(this UrlHelper url)
    {
        return url.Content(ImagesFolder);
    }
}
```

The above code resides in `/Helper/ExtensionMethods.cs`. It works just fine but I need to add `using MyNamespace.Helper;` in every cshtml where I want to use the `Url.Images()`. I the old days we would add another line to `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="MyNamespace.Helper"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

But the above does not seem to be picked up by Razor. I tried adding my using statement to `_ViewStart.cshtml`, with the same result.

So, what's Razor's way of specifying a using across the entire site?

Comment: Definitely a dupe - just didn't come across it in my searches. Thanks for looking :-)

Answer (score 8):

As the accepted linked answer suggests you can add "using" to all views by adding to  section of config file.

For a particular view you can just use

> @using MyNamespace.Helper